# Power BI - Visual Displays Fine on Desktop but not when I publish it

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Here is my situation.

I built a visual using Power BI Desktop. Everything works fine on this visual, no problem.

When I publish this visual, it errors out. The data that I am using is the same on Desktop vs the server and database I am publishing the report to.

Why could this be? Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Goal: Make the published Power BI report not error out anywhere.

Error message I am getting:

```
Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.
```

**Edit #1:** It's really weird, when I use my table visual and filter for 1 of 3 different values, it works fine, but when I use a combination, that's when it errors out. Weird.

Comment: Does problem appear only in some kind of visuals? Table/chart? This one is build-it? What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: Can you show an example of what error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works but when I use the `COUNTROWS` DAX measure instead of just using a column and selecting `COUNT` from the drop down, it works fine.